# No plot displayed with R shiny and reactive

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I want to to create an interactive line plot in R shiny that should allow to choose which level of variable stored in V1 column of data frame is displayed in a dropdown menu.

Here is the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(Hmisc)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(dplyr)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  setwd("C:/Users/Jakub Kwiatkowski/Desktop/MG")
  

  df <- data.frame(V1 = c("x", "x", "x", "x", "y", "y","y","y", "z", "z", "z", "z"),
                   V2 = c(3, 5, 6, 78, 23, 45, 7, 11, 34, 41, 23, 57),
                   V3 = c(4, 8, 12, 16, 4, 8, 12, 16, 4, 8, 12, 16)
                  )
  
  data <- reactive({
    req(input$V1)
    df %>% filter(V1 %in% input$V1)
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
              plot <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = V3, y = V2, color = V1)) + 
                      #stat_summary(fun.data = mean_sdl, fun.args = list(mult = 1), geom = "errorbar", width = 2) +
                      stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "line", size = 1)+
                      theme_classic()+
                      xlab("\n V1")+
                      ylab("mean value of V2 \n")+
                      theme(legend.title = element_blank(),
                            panel.background = element_blank())+
                      scale_color_manual(values=c("#6f9669", "#edca55", "#cccac2", "#5195bd", "#ed6f87", "#ffa340"))+
                      #scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160), limits = c(10, 150))+
                      #scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(10, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1100), limits = c(10, 1150))
                    theme(panel.background = element_blank())
                    })
}

ui <- basicPage(
  h1("R shiny interactive line chart"),
  selectInput(inputId = "V1",
              label = "Choose type",
              choices = c("x", "y", "z")),
  plotOutput(outputId = "plot")
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

When i run this app, the only thing I get is a panel displaying stated title and a dropdown menu with "x", "y" and "z", but no plot.
This is my first attempt at R Shiny. I have tried to implement solutions from other threads but to no avail.
Please advise.

Comment: Remove the `plot <- ` or add a `return(plot)` in your renderPlot. Additionally to get a plot of the filtered data use `ggplot(data = data(),  ..)`